# Android DialogFragment not showing when show() called in onCreate of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment with a simple indeterminate progress bar in the centre, which i use to show network activity:

```
public class NativeLoadingDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public NativeLoadingDialogFragment() {
    // Blank
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
    ProgressBar indeterminateProgressBar = new ProgressBar(getActivity());
    indeterminateProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setContentView(indeterminateProgressBar);

    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    return dialog;
}

public boolean isShowing() {
    return getDialog() != null;
}
}
```

I have used the dialog fragment throughout my app with no issues, it shows up without issue in lots of places when i call `dialog.show(getFragmentManager, null)`, however when I try to call it in onResume of my settings activity it does not show!

I have an activity for settings, which launches the system settings to change the language of the phone. Once the user changes the language and my activity resumes I detect if the language has changed and do a network call:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    mLoading = new NativeLoadingDialogFragment();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(EXTRA_LANGUAGE)) {
                String language = savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_LANGUAGE);
                String currentLanguage = AppUtils.getDefaultLanguageCode(
                        SmartBankConstant.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
                        SmartBankConstant.SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);
                if (!language.equals(currentLanguage)) {
                    updateLanguage(Language.stringToLanguage(currentLanguage));
                }
            }
        }
   }

   private void updateLanguage(Language newLanguage) {
    ....
    getSpiceManager().execute(new SetLanguageRequest(newLanguage),
            new SetLanguageRequestListener(this));

         mLoading.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
```

The code definitely runs but no dialog appears! If the network call fails I have a retry option that calls the `updateLanguage(Language newLanguage)` method again, and the dialog actually appears that time! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to me you are calling the `show()` method only once, that is to say inside the `updateLanguage()` method. On the first run, the `language.equals(currentLanguag))` check succeeds, so `updateLanguage()` is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach. It checks if the dialog is already displayed, otherwise it shows it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    mLoading = new NativeLoadingDialogFragment();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        ...
    }

    mLoading.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
}

private void updateLanguage(Language newLanguage) {
   ...

   if (mLoading != null && !mLoading.isVisible()) {
       mLoading.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
       getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach.  Is the ".executePendingTransactions()" always recommended for use with loading a dialogfragment?  So that it always loads when the main thread is free to process the loading?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but running fragment transaction in the next loop helped to solve this issue.

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // for some reason this must be called in the next loop
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);
    }
});
```